# Simuate Rolling Of Two Dice and Save Sum In Vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to make this code that rolls two dice and keeps track of the sum in a vector. I came up with the following code but I keep getting range error if I enter a number above 12. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

void simulate(vector<int>&, size_t);
void size_int(const vector<int>, size_t);
void print_vector(const vector<int>&, size_t);

int main()
{
    size_t n;
    cout << "Enter the amount of rolls: ";
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(12);
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
        v[i] = 0;
    }  
    simulate(v, n);
    print_vector(v, n);
}

void simulate(vector<int>& sum, size_t n)
{
    int dice_1, dice_2;
    cout << "Rolling the dice " << n << " times produces:\n";
    srand( time(NULL) ); 
    size_t i;

for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    dice_1 = 1+(rand() % 6); 
    dice_2 = 1+(rand() % 6);

    sum[dice_1+dice_2]++;
    }
}

void print_vector(const vector<int>& v, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;
    double x = 1.0*n;
    cout << "Roll\tFrequency\tProbablity\n";
    for(i = 1;i<v.size();++i)
    {
        cout << i+1 << "\t" << v[i] << "\t\t" << v[i]/x << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You hardcoded the vector size to 12: `vector<int> v(12);`

Comment: resize the vector with the number you typed in. it is limited to 12.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code here is not minimal.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but that loop initializing the vector elements to 0 isn't needed. The constructor can do that: just pass the number of elements and the initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> sum[dice_1+dice_2]++;
> ```

`dice1+dice2` will be a value between 2 and 12 inclusive.  `sum` only has elements 0 to 11 inclusive.  You need to size `sum` to *13* to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As your vector starts from 0
you should store values to

```
sum[dice_1+dice_2-1]++;
```

And while printing.

start from

```
for(i=0....)
```